# XeTeX + polyglossia: Trying to get greek text in PDF bookmarks

Tags: xetex, bookmarks, polyglossia, greek

Although I've googled extensively to find a solution, most of the related information online is about `babel`. I'm working with `polyglossia` and can't get the pdf bookmarks to appear in greek, although I have `unicode` set for `hyperref`, I've tried the `bookmark` package and several other suggestions online.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Liberation Sans}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=sans]{greek}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
            bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Συμπεράσματα}
Συμπεράσματα

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post an `MWE` that reproduces the issue? I use Polyglossia and Hyperref without any issues.

Comment: @Jörg there you go, sorry I forgot to add an example.

Comment: This compiles fine on my machine and I have `Συμπεράσματα` as a bookmark in the PDF. Could it be font related? I used Minion Pro as I don't have Liberation. Anyway, remove `unicode` from the `hyperref` setup. You don't need it and it causes a `Failed to convert input string to UTF16` warning.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try with a different font and see if it works.

Comment: Actually, it was solved just by removing the `unicode` option in hyperref. Thanks! You might want to submit an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I could still compile with `unicode` just got the "UTF16" warning. I don't know why omitting `unicode` helps, AFAIK `hyperref` detects `unicode` automatically when `XeTeX` is used. Maybe someone can tune-in and explain what's going on.

Comment: Could it be that this font has issues with unicode? I have no idea, just wild guessing.

Comment: @Jörg Please, add an answer. Removing the `unicode` option is just what's needed. The "Failed to convert" message can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `unicode` option in the `hyperref` setup and the bookmarks will be generated correctly.